# correct way to add to path in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I added a binary to path using:

```
export PATH=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/samtools-1.2:$PATH
```

and I can see it if I:

```
echo $PATH
```

However I keep getting samtools command not found.  So my question is it better to add to path like this:

```
echo 'export PATH=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/samtools-1.2:$PATH/' >> .bashrc
```

or is there a better way?

Comment: I think that there's something else wrong if $PATH seems to be correct after your export. It should work like that just fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you have root access you can edit `/etc/environment` for permanent change.

But i would use the .bashrc file to change the path variable only for the user.

And for the "not found" Problem.
Look at the File permissions.

- Is the file executable?
- Do You have the right to execute the file?